# Which compute node did a Sun Grid Engine job execute on?

Tags: cluster, hpc, gridengine

What is the easiest way to determine which node a compute job was executed on, using Sun Grid Engine?

qstat seems to only list running/queued jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow... earned tumbleweed badge on this one!

The answer, if anyone else ever needs it is

```
 qacct -j 221466
```

where 221466 is the job id